# TP4056 DW01A Problem

Tags: mosfet, battery-charging, lithium-ion, discharge, tp4056

I have TP4056 with protection circuit.

In charging, Everything is OK.

- OC : VDD - VBAT
- OD : VDD - VBAT

While the battery is charging, the circuit continues to work on the battery when the charging current is cut off.In this case, Everything is OK.

- OC : VDD - VBAT
- OD : VDD - VBAT

**After disconnecting and reconnecting the battery cable with the charging current cut off, between GND and BAT_GND pins is open circuited by DW01A. In this case Everything is NOK. :(
Because:**

- OC : VDD - VBAT
- OD : 0V

**So,between GND and BAT_GND pins is open circuited.**

Notes:

- Measurements of OD and OC are referenced to BAT_GND. :)
- Charger components is only mounted. Output voltage that is VDD-VBAT connects to 1kohm.
- Only one battery is used in my pcb. j6 connector not used.

Do you see any problems that I'm not seeing in my circuit connection or system? **I am waiting your comments :)**

[image]

Comment: Is it possible the battery protection circuit sensed an under-voltage condition when you disconnected the battery? What does its datasheet say about how to clear that condition?

Comment: Have to say that your choice of VDD-VBATT as a signal name is incredibly confusing, especially when you start adding spaces to it. What's wrong with just VBATT?

Comment: Ralated datasheet is very bad :( I didnt find that you say.  Why does it OK when first disconnected the charger current?   Why does it NOK when  reconnected the battery? @user_1818839

Comment: you are right. There is my revision list for this sitution. @Finbarr

Comment: "OD : 0V" - what is the actual voltage across the battery when this is happening?

Comment: about 4V. @Finbarr